# Do I have to prime plastic bumper?

Tags: paint, bumper, paint-clearcoat, plastic

This is my first time painting my car's plastic bumper and of course I made a mistake. I forgot to put on a layer of primer before the base coat. Now the base coat is already on, should I sand it off and start over or bite the bullet and continue with mid coat and clear coat?

Before applying the base coat, I sanded the entire bumper with 400 grit wet sandpaper. 60% of the area are down to bare plastic.

If I continue without the primer, how long will it last before peeling again?

Comment: When you sanded the bumper, was there evidence of a primer? If so you should prime it.

Comment: Did you use or add plastic  additive to the paint?  Without the additive the paint will crack when the bumper flexes.

Comment: I used this paint. https://www.amazon.com/Harpy-Motors-2001-2001-DIAMOND-Guaranteed/dp/B079RRYK93

Comment: The base coat is dry, I'll try to flex it tomorrow see if it cracks.